# CGContext.init for ARGB image returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, bitmap, cgcontext, cgimage

I'm trying to create a CGContext and fill it with an array of pixels with an ARGB format. I've successfully created the pixel array, but when I try to create the CGContext with CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB and CGImageAlphaInfo.first, it returns nil.

```swift
func generateBitmapImage8bit() -> CGImage {
    let width = params[0]
    let height = params[1]
    let bitmapBytesPerRow = width * 4

    let context = CGContext(data: nil,
                            width: width,
                            height: height,
                            bitsPerComponent: 8,
                            bytesPerRow: bitmapBytesPerRow,
                            space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), //<-
        bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.first.rawValue)

    context!.data!.storeBytes(of: rasterArray, as: [Int].self)

    let image = context!.makeImage()
    return image!
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the [Supported Pixel Formats](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB).

Seems like you use incorrect configuration (CGImageAlphaInfo.first). For 8 bitsPerComponent and RGB color space you have only the following valid alpha options:

- kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst
- kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast
- kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst
- kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast

You can also try setting **CGBITMAP_CONTEXT_LOG_ERRORS** environment variable in your scheme to get more information in runtime.